# Why to use this.data in the end of the method? to save data?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

Sorry its may be a question for newbies, but why to use `this.data` to save data in plugin?

I see that a lot of people uses that syntex:

```
init: (options) ->
  defaults = {}
  data = {}
  data.options = $.extend defaults, options
  this.data "ct-meta", data
```

or

```
start: -> 
  data = this.data
  data.options.theOne = 'Neo'
  this.data "ct-meta", data
```

Why to use `this.data "ct-meta", data` if it works good without it, if we have `data = this.data`
What I'm missing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `this.data("ct-meta", data)` the `data` object is accessible from outside of the plugin.

Example:

```
$(".some-class").myplugin({ some: "data" });
```

Later you can do:

```
var pluginData = $(".some-class").data("ct-meta");
```

...and you get the data object.

See what [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) does:

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element. Returns the value that was set.

Comment: But how it may be helpful, I just can do `var pluginData = $(".some-class").data("options");` and the code works  too.

Comment: @GEkk Maybe the plugin developer wants to expose them this way. Like I mentioned, you can have access to the plugin options, and if I'm not wrong to the object reference–if this is so, you can even change the options.